# Cannot read properties of null ( play ) when leaving the component

Tags: javascript, audio, svelte, sveltekit

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    let phrase = "Head Admin Esports Middle East organization ( es.me website) and Project Manager at Arab Esports Website."
    let typedChar = "";
    let index = 0;
    let aud;

    const  typing = () =>  {
        setInterval(async () => {
            if (index < phrase.length) {
                typedChar += phrase[index];
                index++;
                await aud.play()
            } else {
                clearInterval()
            }
        }, 20)
    }
    onMount(() => {
        typing()
    })
</script>

<audio bind:this={aud} src={typingAudio} />
```

[image]

Here I am showing the data in typing effect I wanted to add sound to this typing effect it works fine as I wanted but when I leave the component mid typing it shows Cannot read properties of null ( play ) error

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve], not as an image. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be because the interval isn't cleared - there's neither an id provided in the call inside `typing` nor is it cleared when the component is destroyed

> [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)  - If the parameter provided does not identify a previously established action, this method does nothing.

```js
    let interval

    const  typing = () =>  {
        interval = setInterval(async () => {
            if (index < phrase.length) {
                typedChar += phrase[index];
                index++;
                await aud.play()
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval)
            }
        }, 20)
    }

    onMount(() => {
        typing()
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    })
```

Alternatively to [`onDestroy`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-ondestroy)

> If a function is returned from onMount, it will be called when the component is unmounted.

(playing the audio might be blocked if the user hasn't yet interacted with the page)